# Detect object on the on screen

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a scroll view with several elements (label, button...), I need to display an image when a button appears on the screen while I'm scrolling.

I can detect when button appears on the screen like this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
let offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset
let onScreen = CGRectOffset(self.scrollView.frame, offset.x, offset.y)
if CGRectIntersectsRect(onScreen, self.button.frame) {
    ...
}
```

}

But I want to get all buttons (maybe in array with tags) which appear on the screen after scrolling.

How can I do this?

Comment: What you're doing will work, so what's the issue? You can make an array with all of the views if you need to, just like you said.

Comment: I add all button in code from http request. And I set each button tag with some ID. This is ID = ID image. If you go through all the buttons when you stop scrolling it will be very long.

Comment: One possible optimization is to add all of the buttons to an array that you can access directly rather than having to look them up by tags. You can also check the visibility a little quicker by only comparing the buttons' frame origin against the content offset of the scrollview since you don't really care about the full intersection. Other than that, you haven't given enough info for us to be able to provide any other useful optimizations.

Comment: No, I think it will be more slowly, that get all button's tag from the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your buttons are in an array, then use an NSSet and for the scrolling buttons use an NSMutableSet.

So, just before scrolling, do the following:

```
NSMutableSet *scrolledButtons = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
```

And as they scroll, add them:

```
[scrolledButtons addObject:aButton];
```

Then when finished, just do a check:

```
NSSet *allMyButtons = [NSSet setWithArray:self.myArrayOfButtons];
if ([allMyButtons equalToSet:scrolledButtons]) {
    // whatever
}
```

And apologies for doing it in Obj-C... my Swift is not quite up to snuff and I'm doing this quickly.

Comment: No, no, no. I want to get all objects tag (unbutton, uilabel) which appear on the screen after scrolling.